# Reassign position and scale of the navigation gizmo

Tags: interface

in the will to build a -limited Blender edition- easy to use for 3D model visualization, I want to move and scale the navigation gizmo. It seems that is not declared in a python file.

Comment: Yes that one would be done in the C code and is fixed in location and size. You could work around it by making a [viewport overlay](https://blog.michelanders.nl/2019/02/working-with-new-opengl-functionality.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm answering myself in case this helps anyone in the future. The file to edit is `\blender\source\blender\editors\space_view3d\view3d_gizmo_navigate`.