# Reposition navigation gizmo

Tags: 3d-view, interface, axis

As a pen user and newbie, I rely greatly on clicking on buttons over key shortcuts. As a left handed user, I would benefit from essentially flipping the UI horizontally, so tools are more reachable. This can be done with most elements, including the toolbar and sidebar (as per [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/212193/124280) answer). The only thing I couldn't figure out how to move are the navigation tools. Is there a way to move the axis ball and the buttons under it to the left of the viewport?

[image]

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/136848/reassign-position-and-scale-of-the-navigation-gizmo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be an way to do it with BPY code that I am unaware of.

On the other hand, you can toggle the viewport 3D gizmo visibility by clicking the *Viewport Gizmos* popover menu in the *3D View* header, then clicking the option *Navigate*.

There is also the shortcut  <kbd>~</kbd> to toggle the gizmo visibility.

[image]

Comment: I should've clarified, I'm not looking for a programmatic solution, only a UI option. I'll accept this answer as a 'no' and try hitting up Right Click Select.